# Is there a possible memory leak for the codes below?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, initialization, memset, unsigned-char

```
    unsigned char *bin_data;
    unsigned char *bin_model;

    bin_data = new unsigned char[200];
    memset(bin_data, 0, 200);
    bin_model = new unsigned char[200];
    memset(bin_model, 0, 200);
```

I was reviewing the code above and I have a gut feel that it might cause a memory leak, but I logically cannot find the reason.

I am thinking it is because we have memset a pointer to 0, the address of the data might be lost. What we wanted to do was just to initialize bin_data and bin_model before acquiring data from an interface which will be used in further processing, since acquiring the data has a chance to fail.

Will the code above cause any problems?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you educate me please?

Comment: Dont mix C, C++ and Java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
memset(bin_data, 0, 200);
```

...writes 200 zeros starting at the address pointed by `bin_data`. [`memset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) doesn't overwrite the pointer itself to zero. The address is kept intact.

If there is a memory leak in this code it would be due to a lack of `delete[]`.

Comment: I understand. It all makes sense now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to delete the allocated memory to prevent memory leak:

```
delete[] bin_data;
delete[] bin_model;
```

But it's not recommended to use raw `new` and `delete`, a better solution is to use a `vector`, it also initializes the data to zero:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> bin_data(200);
```

If you need a non-const pointer to the data, you can use a `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` which automatically frees the memory.

C++11:

```
auto bin_data = std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>(new unsigned char[200]);
```

C++14:

```
auto bin_data = std::make_uniue<unsigned char[]>(200);
```

And you can get the underlying pointer with `bin_data.get()`

Comment: Thanks @krisz. I was planning to suggest unique pointers to improve the codes above too. :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking it is because we have memset a pointer to 0, the address of the data might be lost.

`memset` takes an address as the first value.  The pointer you passed points to a location in the heap.  The pointer itself is stored on the stack.  The buffer pointed to is overwritten, the pointer is untouched.

Since you tagged this "C++" you should really heed the advice in the other answers: smart pointers are the way to go, don't use naked pointers for heap allocations like these.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have problems if you did not clear your memory you added on the heap (using the keyword delete) or left a dangling pointer.